# App Engine async syntax -- what does "raise" do in this example?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to understand this code block from [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async):

```
@ndb.tasklet
def get_cart_plus_offers(acct):
    cart, offers = yield get_cart_async(acct), get_offers_async(acct)
    raise ndb.Return((cart, offers))
```

Does `raise` in this case just act as a `return` statement? I normally associate `raise` with raising errors, but is this just a way to express return? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async? It explains quite clearly how `raise` and `yield` are used differently in Tasklets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasklets are meant to be generators, and in generators, a `return` has different semantics; it *ends* the generator. As such, you cannot use `return` to return a value from a generator in Python 2:

```
>>> def foo():
...     yield None
...     return 1
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

Thus, you need a different mechanism to return a value and end the tasklet; `raise` with a special exception class is used instead.